# How can two services communicate with each other in a bi-directional way?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In one way by events, in other by calling methods. I trying to realize aggregate pattern in my app.

I have AuthService, here i handle auth results and emit the event.

```
if (auth) { this.eAuth.emit(true) } else { this.eAuth.emit(false) }
```

I can subscribe in AuthComponent

```
_authService.eAuth.subscribe( (isAuth) => this.handleAuthResult(isAuth) )
```

And it works perfect. But AggregateService also need to know about this and broadcast this information to UserService, LoadDataService and so on.

How to do it?

upd: my AggregateService doesn't have component and I already inject AuthService into it.

Comment: EventEmitter does not only work between Service and Component, they are actually useful between components, one component can react to an event emitted by another component and call a different service when it happens.

Comment: My AggregateService doesn't have component.

Comment: You can inject a service into another service and call it whenever you want, you don't have to use EventEmitters.

Comment: I already inject AuthServise into AggregateService for using it's methods, and can't inject AggregateService into AuthService at the same time.

Comment: So is your question/problem really: how can two services communicate with each other in a bi-directional way?

Comment: in fact yes. In one way by events, in other by calling methods. I can't realize aggregate pattern in Angular2?

Comment: thanks for comments, I updated the question.

Comment: The `subscribe` method is from an `Observable` object that comes from a library callled RxJS, you don't `emit` custom events with it, you emit certain defined events, like `onNext` or `onCompleted` See: https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-creating-an-observable

Comment: @MarkRajcok no, I'm telling @user3331456 that `this.eAuth.emit` will not cause the `subscribe` to fire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If ServiceA is injected into ServiceB, ServiceB can call methods on ServiceA (hence ServiceB → ServiceA communication) and it can `subscribe()` to any Obervable that ServiceA might expose (hence ServiceA → to ServiceB communication).

What's missing is ServiceA's ability to directly call methods on ServiceB.  This is often not recommended, as it creates coupling between the services.  ServiceA should emit events using `next()` on the Observable that ServiceB can `subscribe()` to, then ServiceB can call the appropriate method(s) on itself.

However, if you really need this to work, here is one way to do it: have ServiceB call some kind of `registerService(this)` method on ServiceA.  The type of the argument should be an interface rather than a concrete type, to limit coupling.  Then ServiceA will have a reference to ServiceB and it can call methods on it.

```
interface SomeInterface {
  public methodOne();
  public methodTwo();
}
```

```
import {SomeInterface} from './some-interface';
export class ServiceA {
    registerService(someService:SomeInterface) {
       someService.methodOne(this);
       // you'll probably want to store someService in this object
    }
}
```

ServiceB should `implement` that interface -- i.e., implement the set of methods that ServiceA can call.

```
import {SomeInterface} from './some-interface';
export class ServiceB implements SomeInterface {
    constructor(private _serviceA: ServiceA) {
       _serviceA.registerService(this);
    }
    methodOne(who) {
       console.log('hello from ServiceB.methodOne(), called by', who);
    }        
    methodTwo() { ... }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YLiEg1GHUoo4CSz2A8WX?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: You said that "If ServiceA is injected into ServiceB, it can subscribe() to any EventEmitters that ServiceA might expose". ServiceA is also injected to ServiceC. ServiceB call method of ServiceA →  ServiceA emit event →  I can subscribe in ServiceB and it works (but no need). I need to subscribe on it in ServiceC, but can't make it works. http://plnkr.co/edit/b4W09zOqoOLUgI3DRvDv

Comment: @ivanesi, there were a lot of problems with your plunker.  I believe I fixed them... have a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TfsHY79aTxngWiKBWeZt?p=preview).