# How root-level service interact with component-level service in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one module in my Angular app.
This module contains several components : Comp1, Comp2, ...
And one service Service1 is associated with the root component of the module CompRoot.
Another Service Service2 is app-level instance (singleton) and need to interact with Service1.
How can I manage to make them communicate (fields and methods) ?

The purpose of this is to reset Service1 when I'm navigating between routes but keep data in Service2.

Comment: This can help [how-can-two-services-communicate-with-each-other-in-a-bi-directional-way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953132/how-can-two-services-communicate-with-each-other-in-a-bi-directional-way)